# Are there market makers in EXT hours?

Tags: united-states, after-hours-trading, market-making

Are there market makers in EXT hours? or they only work during regular hours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually not.

> There may be no market makers
> actively making markets in most or all stocks.

https://www.sec.gov/files/afterhourtrading.pdf

> Market makers and specialists generally do not participate in after-hours trading, which can limit liquidity

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended-hours_trading

> The biggest difference between after hours and market hours trading is the thin liquidity, which results in very wide bid/ask spreads. It’s a very dangerous landscape. **Liquidity tends to be thin with excessively wide spreads since market makers and specialists have left for the day.** Most stocks have no activity in the after hours markets. However, when news comes out after the close, the underlying stocks may have some trade-able action.

https://www.investorsunderground.com/after-hours-trading/